# gb4e item numbers with tikz-qtree trees

Tags: tikz-qtree, linguistics, gb4e

I am using gb4e for numbered examples in my dissertation, since most of my examples are interlinear glosses. I am also including syntax trees, using tikz-qtree. One problem, though, is how to keep item numbers together with the trees. The university's editorial office is notoriously picky (and in this case, so am I). Below is a MWE illustrating the issue.

How do I keep the example number with the tree (without having to manually fix each problem)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree,tikz-qtree-compat}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center, anchor=north}}
\begin{document}
The relevant structure in \ref{tree:opt-marker-verb-move} shows the necessary movement for the verb to precede the suffix. XP refers to some unknown structure to which the verb is drawn.
\lipsum[3-6]
\begin{exe}
\ex
\leavevmode\vadjust{\vspace{-\baselineskip}}\newline %this command makes the example number line up with the top of the tree, rather than the bottom
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}}
\Tree [.XP \node(XP){}; 
[.\textsc{FocusP} =em 
[.TP
[.vP {} 
[.VP {} 
[.V \node(VERB){puv}; ] 
] ] ] ] ]
\draw[->] (VERB) [in=-130,out=-180,looseness=1.5] to (XP);
\end{tikzpicture}\label{tree:opt-marker-verb-move}
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than trying to hack the position of the tikzpicture environment using `\vadjust` it is better to adjust the `baseline` of the tikzpicture environment. Doing this puts your graph onto the second page with the equation number:

[image]

To do this I have commented out your hack using `\vadjust` and added `baseline=(current bounding box.center)` to the tikzpicture environment.

Here's the adjusted version of your code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree,tikz-qtree-compat}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center, anchor=north}}
\begin{document}
The relevant structure in \ref{tree:opt-marker-verb-move} shows the necessary movement for the verb to precede the suffix. XP refers to some unknown structure to which the verb is drawn.
\lipsum[3-6]
\begin{exe}
\ex
%\leavevmode\vadjust{\vspace{-\baselineskip}}\newline %this command makes the example number line up with the top of the tree, rather than the bottom
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}}
\Tree [.XP \node(XP){};
[.\textsc{FocusP} =em
[.TP
[.vP {}
[.VP {}
[.V \node(VERB){puv}; ]
] ] ] ] ]
\draw[->] (VERB) [in=-130,out=-180,looseness=1.5] to (XP);
\end{tikzpicture}\label{tree:opt-marker-verb-move}
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Andrew, Your solution was great, with just one little tweak. I really need the top of the tree to align with the example number (rather than having the example number appear in the middle of tree). I used [baseline=(current bounding box.north)], and it did exactly what I needed it to do. Thanks for putting me on the right track.

Comment: @ToddAO to achieve that behavior, you can also simply write `\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]`, rather than typing out the whole `baseline=(current bounding box.north)`.