# Moving number labelling on forest linguistics diagrams

Tags: numbering, linguistics, forest, examples, gb4e

I'm using the forest package for some linguistics diagrams at the moment and I need to number them. However, the label for the numbering is aligned with the bottom of the digram when I want to have it aligned with the top.

Using some dummy examples, here's the current code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Brill}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{syll/.style=
   {for tree={parent anchor=south,child anchor=north,
              align=center,base=bottom sep=0pt,
              where n children=0{tier=seg}{}}}}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex
\begin{forest}syll
[,phantom, s sep=1em
[σ [O [p,tier=seg ]]
      [R [μ [aː,name=aa] ] [μ,name=M [,phantom] ]]]
[σ [O [p,tier=seg ]]
      [R [μ [a] ]]]
]
\draw (M.south) -- (aa.north);
\end{forest}
\end{exe}
\begin{exe}
\ex
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{xlist}
\ex
\begin{forest}syll
[,phantom, s sep=1em
[σ [O [p,tier=seg ]]
      [R [μ [aː,name=aa] ] [μ,name=M [,phantom] ]]]
[σ [O [p,tier=seg ]]
      [R [μ [a] ]]]
]
\draw (M.south) -- (aa.north);
\end{forest}
\ex
\begin{forest}syll
[,phantom, s sep=1em
[σ [O [l ]]
      [R [μ [a]] [μ [l,name=LL]]]]
[σ [O,name=O [,phantom] ]
      [R [μ [a] [l]]]]
]
\draw[dashed] (O.south) -- (LL.north);
\end{forest}
\end{xlist}
\end{multicols}
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

This gives me something like this:
[image]

When I want something more like this:

[image]

I'm using TeXmaker and compiling using XeLaTeX.

Comment: Please see my edit, where I figured out the appropriate incantation to make a new environment that does this automatically.

Comment: This is not quite a duplicate of [gb4e item numbers with tikz-qtree trees](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202467/gb4e-item-numbers-with-tikz-qtree-trees) because that is for `tikz-qtree`, but really the underlying issue for both is that this has to do with the external alignment of a `tikzpicture` (which is what a `forest` tree really is). You would have the same issue if you made some other kind of diagram in `tikz` and wanted to put it within a numbered example (whether using `gb4e`, `linguex`, or `expex`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDITED to create new environment `newforest`, to automatically do the shift.

This is the meat of the EDIT

```
\usepackage{xpatch,letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro\newforest\forest
\LetLtxMacro\endnewforest\endforest
\xpretocmd{\newforest}{\setbox\ForBox=\hbox\bgroup}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\endnewforest}{\egroup\begingroup%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\baselineskip-\ht\ForBox}{\usebox{\ForBox}}\endgroup}{}{}
\newsavebox{\ForBox}
```

based on the answer at [Patch tabular environment with colorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98415/patch-tabular-environment-with-colorbox)

Note: I converted to pdflatex, since I did not have Brill font.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Brill}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{syll/.style=
   {for tree={parent anchor=south,child anchor=north,
              align=center,base=bottom sep=0pt,
              where n children=0{tier=seg}{}}}}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{xpatch,letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro\newforest\forest
\LetLtxMacro\endnewforest\endforest
\xpretocmd{\newforest}{\setbox\ForBox=\hbox\bgroup}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\endnewforest}{\egroup\begingroup%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\baselineskip-\ht\ForBox}{\usebox{\ForBox}}\endgroup}{}{}
\newsavebox{\ForBox}
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex
\begin{newforest}syll
[,phantom, s sep=1em
[$\sigma$ [O [p,tier=seg ]]
      [R [$\mu$ [aː,name=aa] ] [$\mu$,name=M [,phantom] ]]]
[$\sigma$ [O [p,tier=seg ]]
      [R [$\mu$ [a] ]]]
]
\draw (M.south) -- (aa.north);
\end{newforest}
\end{exe}
\begin{exe}
\ex
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{xlist}
\ex
\begin{newforest}syll
[,phantom, s sep=1em
[$\sigma$ [O [p,tier=seg ]]
      [R [$\mu$ [aː,name=aa] ] [$\mu$,name=M [,phantom] ]]]
[$\sigma$ [O [p,tier=seg ]]
      [R [$\mu$ [a] ]]]
]
\draw (M.south) -- (aa.north);
\end{newforest}
\ex
\begin{newforest}syll
[,phantom, s sep=1em
[$\sigma$ [O [l ]]
      [R [$\mu$ [a]] [$\mu$ [l,name=LL]]]]
[$\sigma$ [O,name=O [,phantom] ]
      [R [$\mu$ [a] [l]]]]
]
\draw[dashed] (O.south) -- (LL.north);
\end{newforest}
\end{xlist}
\end{multicols}
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That worked exactly as I wanted. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ingenious but wouldn't it be easier to use Forest's option?

Comment: @cfr That would require that I learn 'forest`, now wouldn't it :^)?  +1 to you.

Comment: True. And you ought to have +1 for generality. Though, actually, I think it is TikZ rather than Forest, really. (But you have to know how Forest passes the option, I guess ...)

Answer (score 6):

Forest provides the option `baseline` which aligns the current node with TeX's baseline when setting the tree. For this case, we can include the option in the definition of the `syll` style and automatically set the option. The code below sets the root node as the baseline if it is not empty or its first child otherwise.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Brill}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{%
  syll/.style={%
    for tree={
      parent anchor=south,
      child anchor=north,
      align=center,
      base=bottom sep=0pt,
      if n children=0{%
        tier=seg,
      }{},
    },
    where level=0{%
      delay={%
        if content={}{for n=1{baseline}}{baseline}
      }
    }{},
  },
}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex
\begin{forest}syll
[,phantom, s sep=1em
[σ [O [p,tier=seg ]]
      [R [μ [aː,name=aa] ] [μ,name=M [,phantom] ]]]
[σ [O [p,tier=seg ]]
      [R [μ [a] ]]]
]
\draw (M.south) -- (aa.north);
\end{forest}
\end{exe}
\begin{exe}
\ex
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{xlist}
\ex
\begin{forest}syll
[,phantom, s sep=1em
[σ [O [p,tier=seg ]]
      [R [μ [aː,name=aa] ] [μ,name=M [,phantom] ]]]
[σ [O [p,tier=seg ]]
      [R [μ [a] ]]]
]
\draw (M.south) -- (aa.north);
\end{forest}
\ex
\begin{forest}syll
[,phantom, s sep=1em
[σ [O [l ]]
      [R [μ [a]] [μ [l,name=LL]]]]
[σ [O,name=O [,phantom] ]
      [R [μ [a] [l]]]]
]
\draw[dashed] (O.south) -- (LL.north);
\end{forest}
\end{xlist}
\end{multicols}
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

[image: baseline alignment]

Note that I've changed `where n children=0 ...` to an `if` since it is inside the scope of a `for tree` already and `where`, unlike `if`, inserts `for tree` automatically. It doesn't really do any harm here but `for tree={for tree={...}}` is unnecessarily complicated and just makes Forest run through all the nodes in the tree *n* times, where *n* is the number of nodes in the tree. (At least, I assume so. Unless Forest does something clever to catch this kind of case.)

If you have version 2+ of Forest, you might also wish to look at the `linguistics` library which applies some options by default, saving you the trouble.